# How do we communicate computers(NETWORK Adapter) using two different data encodings?

Tags: adapter, network, encoding

For example, one of the computers use NRZ encoding, and the other one use manchester encoding. How should the communication be? Or what would be the result if we used a repeater? Is it possible ?

Comment: Manchester encoding is a subset of NRZ so your question is flawed.

Comment: You are right .I mean two different coding. Unipolar polar or bipolar etc.

Comment: please provide your definition of network adapter and what they could possibly have to do with nrz vs manchester or bipolar vs unipolar?

Comment: the term `protocol converter` popped into my head

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about NRZ versus Manchester, then you are down at the physical level, nowhere near to the computer yet.

If two computers are to communicate, then they must be compatible at several levels of the protocol stack. A simple repeater is not going to fix things.

Comment: Two computers are to communicate with different coding techniques. What do you mean "compatible at several levels"  ?

Comment: The length of a word, whether there's parity or not, whether there's flow control, how long a message is - fixed length or demarked by special characters, whether there's a checksum, etc etc etc.